# Convert sheet content to table without headers

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I want to write a vba function that convert the content of a sheet from a specific workbook into a table

```vb
Sub DataToTable(wb As Workbook)

    Dim tb1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set tb1 = ws.Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlNo
    
    ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tb1).Name = "source"
    
End Sub
```

I have a compilation error at Set tb1 line

Comment: You miss parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a variable to a range and in the same line sort it.

This will work:

```vb
Sub DataToTable(ws as Worksheet)

    Dim tb1 As Range    
    Set tb1 = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tb1, xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlGuess)
    With lo
        .Name = "source"
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Add2 lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
            .Apply
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

I am passing the **worksheet** to that sub - it makes more sense than passing a workbook and relying on the activesheet of the workbook.

Comment: You forgot to define ws and to change xlListObjectHasHeaders to xlNo but THANK YOU!!

Comment: `ws` is defined as parameter for the sub. Please accept the answer if it helped you.